# How to assign an @EntityGraph annotation to Spring Data JPA repository .findAll()

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Annotating the Spring Data JPA repository method `findAll()` with `@EntityGraph`:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
[...]

public interface OptgrpRepository extends JpaRepository<Optgrp> {

@EntityGraph(value = "Optgrp.sysoptions")
List<Optgrp> findAll();
```

}

leads to this error message:

`org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type Optgrp!`

Same error happens when changing `findAll()` to other names:

`findAllWithDetail()` --> `No property findAllWithDetail found for type Optgrp!`

`findWithDetailAll()` --> `No property findWithDetailAll found for type Optgrp!`

Question: Is it at all possible to use the `@EntityGraph` annotation on a Spring Data JPA repository method that finds all entities?

EDIT: as asked in the comment, here's the extract from the `Optgrp` entity class:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Optgrp.sysoptions", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("sysoptions"))
public class Optgrp implements Serializable {
    [...]
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="optgrp", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @OrderBy(clause = "ordnr ASC")
    private List<Sysoption> sysoptions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And the `Sysoption` entity class as well:

```
@Entity
public class Sysoption implements Serializable {
[...]
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "optgrp_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Optgrp optgrp;
}
```

Comment: Did you define `@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Optgrp.sysoptions",
  attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("sysoptions"))` on your domain Entity?

Comment: @NitinArora Yes, the `NamedEntityGraph`is defined in the `Optgrp` domain entity class. I've edited the question.

Comment: Can you share the definition of Sysoption as well?

Comment: @NitinArora Ok, added Sysoption as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the name `findByIdNotNull` is one way to combine both findAll() and entity graph:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "Optgrp.sysoptions")
List<Optgrp> findByIdNotNull();
```

Answer (score 11):

For all, who are using Stack Overflow as knowledge database too, I record a new status to Markus Pscheidts challenge. Three years and six months later the `@EntityGraph` annotation works now directly at the `findAll()` function in Spring Data `JpaRepository`, as Markus original expected.

```
@Repository
public interface ImportMovieDAO extends JpaRepository<ImportMovie, Long> {
  @NotNull
  @Override
  @EntityGraph(value = "graph.ImportMovie.videoPaths")
  List<ImportMovie> findAll();
}
```

Versions used in the test: Spring Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE with included spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.

Comment: Better late than never :)